# DIVs horizontally aligned in Safari, but not in Chrome

Tags: html, vertical-alignment

Have two with the same id. In Safari they align great, but in Chrome the first div is offset about 15px to the bottom.

HTML:

```
<div id="equipe">
    <div id="equipe-min">
        <img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-5420" alt="Rodrigo Purchio" src="http://www.frangocombatatadoce.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/sobre-nós-04.jpg" style="margin-bottom:-20px;" width="180" height="220">
        <h5>Rodrigo Purchio</h5>
        Designer. Além de marombeiro e nerd, agora é também metido à mestre cuca. Tem 23 anos, trabalha com branding, é formado em Publicidade e Propaganda pela PUC-Rio e tem MBA em Design Estratégico pela ESPM.
    </div>
    <div id="equipe-min">
         <img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-5424" alt="Roberta Pacheco" src="http://www.frangocombatatadoce.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/sobre-nós-05.jpg" style="margin-bottom:-20px;" width="180" height="220">

       <h5>Roberta Pacheco</h5>
       Estudante de arquitetura. Com toda a família apaixonada por comer bem, cozinha desde pequena e é apaixonada por academia desde cedo por influência dos pais, que sempre incentivaram a prática de atividades físicas.
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#equipe {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 100%;
    float: right;
    vertical-align:center;
}

#equipe-min {
    text-align:left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

On Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/kbhsN/1/

But if I use float:left on #equipe-min, the DIVs get aligned, but stay on the left, and I want them to be centered in the wrapper #equipe.

Here's the live page:
http://www.frangocombatatadoce.com/sobre-nos/

Answer (score 0):

does this might help you http://jsfiddle.net/kbhsN/2/

than those divs are centered horizontally if there is only one. is that what you want?

```
#equipe-min {
    /* ... */
    margin:5px auto 5px auto;
    /* ... */
}
```

**UPDATE**

note an id has to be unique and you use them twice so change that to a class

```
.equipe-min {
    /* ... */
    margin:5px auto 5px auto;
    /* ... */
}




<div id="equipe">
    <div class="equipe-min">
        <img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-5420" alt="Rodrigo Purchio" src="http://www.frangocombatatadoce.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/sobre-nós-04.jpg" style="margin-bottom:-20px;" width="180" height="220">
        <h5>Rodrigo Purchio</h5>
        Designer. Além de marombeiro e nerd, agora é também metido à mestre cuca. Tem 23 anos, trabalha com branding, é formado em Publicidade e Propaganda pela PUC-Rio e tem MBA em Design Estratégico pela ESPM.
    </div>
    <div class="equipe-min">
         <img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-5424" alt="Roberta Pacheco" src="http://www.frangocombatatadoce.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/sobre-nós-05.jpg" style="margin-bottom:-20px;" width="180" height="220">

       <h5>Roberta Pacheco</h5>
       Estudante de arquitetura. Com toda a família apaixonada por comer bem, cozinha desde pequena e é apaixonada por academia desde cedo por influência dos pais, que sempre incentivaram a prática de atividades físicas.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually I need to vertically align them in Chrome. They're being displayed like this:

http://i.imgur.com/9uLqMb3.png

Comment: works fine for me: http://de.tinypic.com/r/2vju7o5/5 using chrome Version 32.0.1700.77

Comment: Sorry, I was editing the style.css to try to make it work. Could you see again if it works? I use Chrome 32.0.1700.77 on Mac.

Comment: @purchio I'll use exact the same chrome and for me it works fine as shown in the picture above

Comment: Really strange. But if I remove the text added under the h5, the divs get aligned again. Also tested on my Windows 8 machine running Chrome, they only get aligned without the text.

Comment: If I have only one line of text they display fine, but if I add more lines, this is what happens: http://imgur.com/AqWU4Ac